# Can we make a case for Eurasiatic numerals for one and two?

Tags: proto-indo-european, numerals, reconstruction, altaic-hypothesis

There is a widespread Eurasiatic theory that puts all these families (except PIE) into one group, the case for common numerals for one and two seems more plausible. I also add Chukchi-Kamchadal family hare as it is considered close to PIE. I do not include word forms which seem not to be related.

Below, đ=dʒ

Compare:

```
PIE    Korean Tungusic Burushaski Chukchi PAinu PKartvel Mongolian OTurkic
e̯oinom hana   ömen     hen        ənnen   hine
du̯oe̯   dur    đöör     tóorumo(ten)       tuu   đor      đuirim    tuirem "second" 

Modern Tungusic languages  |  Modern Kartvelian languages
Oroqen Manchu Even            Megrel  Svan   Laz
umun   emu    umūn
đūr    đuu̯e   dūr             žir     đor    žur
```

**ADDENDUM**

I did not include Uralic here even though it is usually considered related to PIE because the Uralic numeral for two is a cognate with PIE word for a pair (***q̆eta̯***), and the numeral for one seems to mean "non-paired" and come from the same root.

But if we consider the PIE word for four, ***q̆etu̯ores***, we can analyze it as a compound q̆et-du̯or-es, that is "a pair of twos". Thus the most ancient PIE form of the word for two was possibly ***du̯or*** (possibly used with nouns with r/n stem?).

Comment: Do you have a set of words showing the same correspondences of segments? Otherwise this is free speculation, and not of much value.

Comment: @ColinFine what do you mean by segments?

Comment: Phonemes, if you will.

Comment: @ColinFine there is a lot of work on this in the frames of Eurasiatic and Altaic theories, my aim was to focus on the numerals for one and two and point out that if we exclude Turkic, Uralic and some other families which have totally different numerals, we can come with at least plausible reconstructions for one and two. The sound correspondences I think mostly were already proposed for these families.

Comment: @ColinFine for instance, the numeral for two in Uralic is cognate for PIE word for a pair (PIU root ket-), so it is not related to the PIE word for two.

Comment: Altaic isn't a "widespread" theory. It's somewhat prominent, but widely rejected (hence you go on "but"). Chukchi-Kamchadal is not "considered" anything. It's not widely known (Does that contain Chuckese? I had come to think that one was made up by @Chuck in wiktionary as a honeypot to catch quacks, because I do see the occoasional similarity). None of the compared languages are in your field of expertise. The PIE root for "two" is commonly given as \*dwo-, you know that. There is no internal derivation for the *-r*, but I guess it might be morphemic, \*-ros; or were reinterpreted as such

Comment: likewise, there is no internal derivation for \*oynos or **eoinom**(?), except that \*-os is regular. It is missing in Hittite, too, who rather reflects \*sem- etc. so I thought \*oynos was proto-nuclear or secondary.

Comment: @vectory I think e̯oinom is neuter/inanimate while e̯oinos is animate/masculine

Comment: @vectory I think PIE had e̯oino- as "one alone" and sem- as "one united". Also, e̯oinos could be derived from the root e̯ei- "to go" (walked away?)

Comment: I'm not sure what deleted my draft, an unnecessary update, or seven days having passed, anyway I'm fed up. Blazek on "Indo-European Numerals" does mention tungusic indeed; also Korean, but w.r.t. \*sem-. Ruhlen et al go a whole lot further; I shouldn't have spent too much time trying to defend that. It was a lot of meta discussion and a large excursion over "seven", second guessing Blazek's account (formal mistake assigning a gloss for Persia to Semitic; a link from "Siebenheit" to \*d-k- "ten", Ruhlens \*TIK "one"; stipulations about sabbath; appreciation for \*?-y-y), but obv. nothing new.

Comment: I do suggest to check out pronomial "one", "no one".

Answer (score 8):

Definitely not.

Two words only aren't enough to establish any kind of relationship.

The best you can do with it is to use them as seeds for possible sound relations and look of regular sound laws with their help. So for instance, do the sound laws for "two" carry over to the numeral for "ten"? What about other basic words reconstructed with a PIE **d*?