# What's the reconstruction of the word for fire in proto-Australian?

Tags: proto-indo-european, comparative-linguistics, reconstruction, australian-languages, proto-world

The word for fire in some modern Australian languages:

```
Tiwi            yikwani
Djinang         junggi
Maung           yungku
Walmajarri      yakun
```

This is strikingly similar to that in PIE:

```
PIE     h₁n̥gʷnís
```

So, what was the form in proto-Australian?

Comment: Pease add some info to the Australian languages (e.g., which Australian language family they belong to). While Proto-Pama-Nyungan is reconstructed, I am not aware of any Proto-Australian as a whole.

Comment: slightly more strong than jk's comment, I don't believe there is any serious proposal for all Australian aboriginal languages belonging to a single family. Instead the use of the term "Australian" is generally taken to solely be a term of convenience as they appear to constitute a language area with several typological similarities. In this respect, they are similar to the Khoi-San languages, which comprise several families with no known connections

Comment: @Tristan well, rthere is much similarity in numerals as well: https://preview.redd.it/u2m19t1lidd61.png?width=506&format=png&auto=webp&s=de42d889bfe1f45cb229ccdef3eecb82f6273c4d

Comment: I see at least two distinct sets there. Regardless, of the Australian languages, most belong to the Pama-Nyungan family mentioned by jk, so there is no surprise in these languages having similar numerals. There are a few other small families, but also several isolates. It's also worth noting that some Australian aboriginal languages appear to have developed their numeral systems relatively recently (presumably from a system more like that of Pirahã), since contact with Europeans, and so similarities between their numerals, and their neighbours', even if unrelated, is to be expected

Comment: @Tristan these numerals do not seem similar to any modern European language though.

Comment: @Tristan don't you know if any scholar regarded Australian and/or Trans New Guinean as Mitian?

Comment: @Tristan although I do not trust Starling much, it lists this root as Nostratic and Eurasiatic: https://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?single=1&basename=%2fdata%2fnostr%2fnostret&text_number=+302&root=config

Comment: When I say neighbours' numerals, I mostly mean their neighbours speaking other aboriginal languages. As I've said, Australian is purely a term of convenience, not a genetic term, and afaik even the most out there macrophylogenists accept mitian as a genetic grouping. Proto-Pama-Nyungan is reconstructed having 1sg & 2sg pronouns in nga- (with case marking) and ñuntu respectively, and proto-trans-new-guinean (to the extent it is reconstructed at all, which is not much) has na & ga, so I don't see how either could be called Mitian

Comment: with these particular languages, Djinang & Walmajarri are Pama-Nyungan, whilst Tiwi is an isolate, and Maung is Iwaidjan (a language family with no known genetic relation to Pama-Nyungan). The similarity here is likely either a coincidence (the rate of coincidence can be estimated, and is higher than many would guess), or the results of borrowings. Given the taboos observed by most aboriginal Australian peoples against e.g. using the name of a recently deceased elder, borrowing is often extensive, even in basic vocabulary

Comment: @Tristan well, of course, I do not know the genetic relationship among these languages, but I observed similarity (which of course can be due to borrowing). What really strikes me are that some TNG languages seem to have numeral systems very similar to some Australian ones, but another thing is that some of those numerals look similar to what I have guessed for "Eurasiatic". First Eurasiatic, and then... this is my prevuous post on the topic https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/35583/can-we-make-a-case-for-eurasiatic-numerals-for-one-and-two

Comment: @Tristan I guessed đuor/đuirim for "two", and then I see it everywhere in Australian and TNG. I guessed hene(n)/hoinem for one, and I see kaman, kwənenoi, kanone in Australinan and TNG... Also I see pune, pinti, puŋi, pukàni in compounds meaning five.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's no real consensus on any sort of "Proto-Australian" reconstruction. Some linguists like Dixon proposed "Australian" as an actual language family, with a common ancestor, but my impression is that this isn't popular any more: most linguists now consider Australian to be a Sprachbund containing multiple not-necessarily-related families.

So even if there was, at some point, a common ancestor of the Australian languages, there's never been a widely-accepted reconstruction of it.

Answer (score 0):

Shapper et al in "Tree, ﬁrewood and ﬁre in the languages of Sahul" calls the word "**dyung(u)**". It is unclear if this is scientific reconstruction or not, but it seems to be the closest we have to one.
The word apparently initially meant "tree" or "firewood".