# What is the reconstructed root for fire in Proto-Uralic or Proto-Finno-Ugric?

Tags: comparative-linguistics, reconstruction, uralic, finno-ugric

Starostin alleges that IE root h₁n̥gʷnís [has cognates](https://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?single=1&basename=%2Fdata%2Fnostr%2Fnostret&text_number=%20302&root=config) in Finno-Urgic.

But I distrust this database and also I would like to know what was the proto-form of the root, particularly, the origin of Mari ǝŋɣä-.

Comment: it's worth noting Starostin only alleges reflexes in Ugric, Mari, & Komi Zyrian. These come from a pretty small subarea of the total Uralic range, so I'd be skeptical of an argument for a proto-Uralic (or even proto-FInno-Ugric if that's a valid subgrouping) reconstruction on this basis. That said wiktionary gives the source of Hungarian ég as proto-Uralic *äŋɜ-, corresponding to Starostin's reconstruction and cites http://uralonet.nytud.hu/eintrag.cgi?locale=en_GB&id_eintrag=45 so it isn't just. Starostin

Comment: @Tristan thanks, I wonder, what the characters in äŋɜ- mean though...

Comment: it's common uralicist notation using the Uralic Phonetic Alphabet. <ä> is a low vowel with front harmony, as in Finnish, <ŋ> is a velar nasal as in the IPA, <ɜ> is an uncertain vowel (i.e. the same as V in Starostin's notation)

Comment: @Tristan thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reconstruction as PIE root h₁n̥gʷnís is highly dubious.
IMO better is H3egni-, even though some comparanda do not fit very well into it (They don't fit in h₁n̥gʷnís either...).
A connection with Mari, Khanty and Hungarian is thinkable, but Komi with a palatal nasal does not seem to fit.

Comment: What do you think about parallels in Australian? https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/38169/whats-the-reconstruction-of-the-word-for-fire-in-proto-australian